# "Priority Nav" breaks when div is floated

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, responsive-design

I'm using the "Priority Navigation" design pattern. For those who aren't quite sure what this is, basically when the viewport width is reduced and there isn't enough space for all the list-items to fix horizontally, they're moved into another nested list so they can still be accessed. This is within a "more" link at the end of the list.

At a basic level, this works fine in my example (below):

http://codepen.io/moy/pen/RrRJBe

The problems I'm having are:

**1)** Because I have another item alongside the navigation, which is floated (and of unknown width), I needed to set `overflow:hidden;` on the nav. This means when the width of the container changes, the nav stays alongside the other content rather than dropping onto the next line. It's fixes that ...the problem is it also means the dropdown on the end isn't visible as it's displayed below the navigation and `overflow: hidden;` is set.

*Any alternative (CSS) fixes for this?*

**2)** Another issue is the nav links need to be positioned to the right. No problem, just float the div right, yeah? Unfortunately it doesn't like this and the page almost crashes - must be something to do with the script trying to calculate the widths? As soon as the nav or it's parent is floated, it breaks!

The list-items are floated left so they display horizontally. Instead I tried using `display: inline-block` and `text-align: right;`. This positions the text correctly but when there's not enough horizontal space the items either wrap or all collapse into the "more" link rather than one-by-one.

-

**Browser requirements:** It's worth noting that my browser support is IE8+, so flexbox is unfortunately out the window. Even if it worked, it would mean that I'd have to find a fix for IE8/9.

Is anyone able to help with this, or maybe there's a plug-in I should take a look at. This script works great when the nav is isolated but as soon as another item is in it's path it becomes a bit tricky. On a previous attempt I got the width of the item which was in the way and subtracted it for the available space. But that isn't that flexible/scalable - but that again, maybe there isn't another way?

Thanks, hope someone can help!

Answer (score 1):

**Part 1**

You can use `clearfix` instead of `overflow: hidden`.

Add the following to the parent element containing `nav`:

```
.wrap:before, .wrap:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}
```

But if you need to support IE8, you can just add element like below to the bottom of the parent element containing `nav`

```
html
<div class="clear"></div>

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Hi there, yeah I normally use that clearfix but with that one the content drops down below the "logo" when the browser is resized.

Comment: Likewise, floating right appears to work on the face of it but when the resize the browser is seems to hang/fall down! Thanks for the replies :)